# allow http iframe on a https page with apache HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, iframe, https

I have a problem with the HTACCESS

I have a web page with an SSL certificate, for example https:// www. example.com

Then i have to inject an iframe from other company on my web. The iframe is not https, its just http and the other company is not about to change this.

So i have to allow on my htaccess this iframe.

I put this iframe on a page that cannot be http

for example, if my entire web is https:// www. example.com i want to turn https:// www. example.com/en/potato to http:// www. example.com/en/potato so i will can inject the http iframe.

I've tried to do

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  !^/en/potato$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/en/potato$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.example.com/en/potato [R=301,L]
```

Any sugestion?

Also the web is made on php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** allow an http iframe in an https webpage. If you include an https webpage that redirect to http, it will be blocked too.

What you can do it try to proxy the content of the iframe through an https server, or ask nicely the owner of the http webpage to add https to his website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've send an email to the owner of the iframe but im not faithful about this. 
I've tried to do now

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  !^/en/potato$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en/potato)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

And now the en/potato starts with http but i get this error from my explorer

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

there's any solution for this?

Comment: Event if you solve the "Too many redirect" error, because in the en the page is http, it will be blocked if inside an iframe of an https webpage. You can't solve that problem with a redirect, it means you can't solve it with an htaccess redirect. Sorry.